# Specs for all android phones

Tags: android, specs

Is there a central place where I can find the specs for the majority of the Android phones available on the market? I want to create avds for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK v6 tools brings sdk addons to the emulator via avd manager instead of the old way..expected release with android Os 2.2  sdk sometime within the next 4 to 6 weeks..

Suppose to simplify the way to integrate those emulator addons with items like google  maps etc..

That is why is some OEMS have been waiting instead of issuing emulator addons..